# I am facing the issue in Angular 5 . *NgFor not working . Please see screenshot

Tags: angular, angular5

please suggest me where i am wrong[image]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Angular 5 questions should not be tagged with `angularjs`

Comment: Also, here's the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngforof. Reading and being able to copy and paste are two fundamental skills that, I'm sure, you have. So use them.

Comment: @jb-nizet apparently writing isn't :D

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the following might help:

1) Use the `let` keyword: `*ngFor="let list of allContacts"`;

2) Rename your variable to exclude spaces `all contacts` vs. `allContacts`.